# How can I call a PHP function from inside a MySQL database table so that the function runs normally?

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a really tough question to ask. He is my issue/question.

Is it possible to put a PHP function inside a MySQL table/cell and have the function run normally when called via a PHP query. If so How can I do it?

Here is my query code:

```
$recent_query = "SELECT * FROM `recently-added` ORDER BY `created` DESC LIMIT 4";

if(!$recent_query_result = $con->query($recent_query)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');

}
```

Here is my loop code that displays the results of the query:

```
while($row = $recent_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo  '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 md-margin-bottom-40">
        <div class="easy-block-v2">
            <div class="easy-bg-v2 rgba-' . $row['color'] . '">New</div>
            <img class="img-bordered" alt="' . $row['image-alt'] . '" src="' . $row['image'] . '">       
            <h3><i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i> ' . $row['site-name'] . '</h3>
            <!-- Begin Recently Added Footer Description -->
        </div>  
    </div>';
}
```

In my database and inside the table 'recently-added' I have a column named 'site-name'. I iterate through the loop and display the results onto my page. In the site name cell I put my PHP function for each record. That function is:

```
<?php star5(); ?>
```

When I refresh the page and look at where the function should be called it's a blank space. Nothing there. When I go to look at the source code to see if there is an error it shows me the exact characters that I put into the cell.  It places the text onto the page and the server does not run the script or interpret the function.

Here is an image of the table in the database. This is in regard to te column 'site-name':

https://i.stack.imgur.com/15LtV.jpg

Been trying to fix this for almost 4 hours now. As always thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the function it's self

```
function star5() {

echo '<li><i class="color-green fa fa-star"></i></li>
      <li><i class="color-green fa fa-star"></i></li>
      <li><i class="color-green fa fa-star"></i></li>
      <li><i class="color-green fa fa-star"></i></li>
      <li><i class="color-green fa fa-star"></i></li>';
}
```

Comment: `eval()`, but what you want is really bad, instead write a PHP mapping logic for this

Comment: don't put php in your db, its almost always a bad idea

Comment: So you want to run star5 how frequently? Also please show what star5 looks like.

Comment: I'd go for solution like this `switch($row['sitename']) { case 1: star5(); break; case 2: someOtherFunction(); break; default: break; }`

Comment: the 5star() function is only an echo statement that echos out 5 small lines of HTML that create 5 stars.

Comment: Did you include those php tags in the database entry? Pretty sure you don't want to.

Comment: The sqitch statement would not work for this specific issue. thanks tho

Comment: Yes i included it with tags and without tags.

Comment: Why it's not gonna work?

Comment: Don't mean to state the obvious, but have you tried inserting an ultra-simple function in the db and calling that from the retrieved result set? Like      "echo 'abc';" ?

Comment: Casue there's 20,000+ sites that i am listings. This is part of a featured page. I only list 4 of each featured site.

Comment: i agree with royal put a value in the db, that is then used to determine what php function is called when you display the data.

Comment: user2356315 I have. No PHP will show up when i call it from the database.

Comment: I don't understand, how many PHP functions would you store in this row?

Comment: There has to be a simple fix to this. Some way to call PHP from my database. While it may be advisable I really need to do it this way. i'm not the greatest PHP programmer and for what I need this works perfectly. If only I could get it to work.

Comment: Royal Bg Each row has a column name 'site-name' and various other columns. That is the only column/row that has and PHP in it the rest is either html or text

Comment: @user3870816 eval() as I said, but it's wrong on many levels, so as I understood, you will be using it on your own risk, then do it :)

Comment: you shouldn't do it this way so asking for advise on how to do it wrong is just a bad idea. If you refuse to listen to the advise of others, don't bother asking.

Comment: You can create functions in mysql, so there's no excuse for putting php in the database. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-function.html

Comment: Royal Bg Thanks for the info. Might i ask how to use eval()? Thanks

Comment: @user3870816 so, insert something like `CUSTOM FUNCTION` in this row and then `if($row['sitename'] == 'CUSTOM FUNCTION') { star5(); } else { echo $row['sitename']; }`, if you only want to call ONE function if it's there, then check if it's a function instead of real html and call it manually, otherwise - display the html, it's one level bettern than eval()

Comment: developerwjk I don't know how to do that. I'm not even sure how or what to learn to learn how to do that. I'm going on what I know at the moment and will change it as I learn more. Im having to learn so much as it is

Comment: Royal Bg Ohhh so you mean put the switch or if statment in the loop? not inside the database cell? So that it's plane text that goes to the if statement?

Comment: @user3870816 exactly :)

Comment: developerwjk no need to be rude. I just told you that I had no idea what to even look for. You could have told me what to Google and I'd have happily looked for it. as i am new to all of this its some times hard to even know what to learn if you dont know what to look for. I have been on google for hours. But what you linked me appears to be what i was looking for so thanks. You to  Royal Bg. both methods will work

Comment: Royal Bg and  developerwjk you should both answer the question. They are both right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best way, but as in the current situation, it's the solution which is most close to the good practices for introducing flags in DB in order to have logic over it.

Imagine you want to control if a user is administrator or not. You can add a column `is_admin` with `1` or `0` values, then while fetching the results you can check `if ($row['is_admin'] == 1) { // proccess the logic for administrator } else { // process logic for normal user }`

This could apply here, as you want to execute backend logic on certain event, or just show the row contents, if the event is not present.

According to be it will be one more level better if you introduce new column for this, and check it in order to know if you should call `star5()` or not, but in the current context you can add a string, on which presentation you will trigger the function.

Let's say the string is `CUSTOM FUNCTION`. Then, if you want to execute `star5()` upon fetch pointer moves on this row, then you add `CUSTOM FUNCTION` string in this row. Otherwise you add the normal content (e.g. real sitename).

Afterwards, when you fetch the records, you perform a simple condition check:

```
if ($row['sitename'] == 'CUSTOM FUNCTION') {
    star5();
} else {
    echo $row['sitename'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using php `eval()` function. For example:

`eval("\$row['site-name'] = \"$row['site-name']\";");`

Also, remove the php tags from the data. Try with only keeping the `star5()` function call.

Check this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_eval.asp) for more details on eval.

Comment: This will work with some more crafting, as eval might need a closing the current php tag, in order to not result in `<?php <?php some code`, but the main problem is that this does not care if the row contains `star5()` or not and will turn every string in arbitrary PHP code. As well as `eval()` is never the answer of a certain issue. If it is, then most probably the issue is wrong.

Comment: Never ***EVER*** use `eval()` combined with user submitted data unless you're 100% sure that data is secured properly. And even then there are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

**I have a solution to run functions inside MySQL row or any other PHP string.**

*e.g., user needs to put a slider that gets its images from a server directory but he doesn't want to copy all the links, make an HTML code, etc.*

The first thing you need to do is to create your own syntax for a function. I chose it to be like this -> [functionName('arg1', 'arg2')].

Create a StringParser class which finds all the occurances of your custom function inside of the given string, takes args and runs a custom function from the CustomFunctions class. Then it substitudes the text of your function inside of the given string to a returned value:

```
protected function substitute($string, $start) {
    $callback = "StringFunctions::".$start;
    $offset = 0;
    $start = '['.$start.'(';
    $end   = ')]';

    do {

        $argsArr = [];
        $argsArrNormal = [];

        $pos = strpos($string, $start, $offset);
        if (!$pos) return $string;

        $args_pos = strlen($start) + $pos;
        $args_len = strpos($string, $end, $args_pos) - $args_pos;
        $args     = substr($string, $args_pos, $args_len);
        $argsArr  = preg_split("/'\s*,\s*'/", trim($args));

        foreach ($argsArr as $arg) {
            $argsArrNormal[] = trim($arg, "'");
        }

        $replaced_value = call_user_func_array($callback, $argsArrNormal);
        $string = str_replace($start.$args.$end, $replaced_value, $string);

        $offset++;

    } while($pos);

    return $string;

}
```

After that, create a StringFunctions class with your custom functions which inherits StringParser. Function filter runs StringParser to check all the custom functions occurancies:

```
public function filter($string) {
    $string = StringParser::substitute($string, "printHTML");
    $string = StringParser::substitute($string, "printText");
    $string = StringParser::substitute($string, "multiply");
    $string = StringParser::substitute($string, "getDate");
    $string = StringParser::substitute($string, "printRect");

    return $string;
}

protected function printHTML(...$tags) 
{
    $result = '';
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $result .= "<$tag>";
    }
    return $result;
}

protected function printText(...$text) 
{
    $result = '';
    foreach($text as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == 0) continue;
        $result .= "<$text[0]>$value</$text[0]>";
    }
    return $result;
}

protected function printRect($amount, $width, $height, $color) 
{
    $result = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
        $result .= "<div style='margin:5px;width:$width;height:$height;background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/$width/$height/?random);display:inline-block'></div>";
    }
    return $result;
}

protected function multiply($number, $times) 
{
    return $number * $times;
}

protected function getDate($args) 
{
    return date($args);
}
```

run a code:

```
$StringFunctions = new StringFunctions(); 

$string = "A string can do more than just being itself[printHTML('hr')] [printRect('3','380','380','#eee')][printHTML('hr','br')] 13 * 14.4 =[multiply('13','14.4')][printHTML('br','br','hr')] [printText('h1','Hello, pony!')] Today is [getDate('Y - m - d')]!Today is [getDate('Y - m - d')]!Today is [getDate('Y - m - d')]!Today is [getDate('Y - m - d')]!";

echo $StringFunctions->filter($string);
```